# Различие в перетаскивании img и div

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop

Есть код

```
<body style='height: 2000px'>
    <div style='background: blue; width:100px; height:100px'></div>
    <img src="https://js.cx/drag-heroes/ball.png">
    <script>
        document.onmousedown = function(event) {
            var tar = event.target;
            if (tar.tagName != 'IMG' && tar.tagName != 'DIV') 
                return;
            tar.style.position = 'absolute';
            document.onmousemove = function(event) {
                tar.style.left = event.pageX - 20 + 'px'; 
                tar.style.top = event.pageY - 20 + 'px';
            }
            tar.onmouseup = function() {
                document.onmousemove = tar.onmouseup = null;
            }
            tar.ondragstart = function() {
                return false;
            }
        }
     </script>
 </body>
```

Если перетаскивать img, то он может выходить за пределы экрана, но прокрутку экрана не вызывает. Если перетаскивать div за пределы экрана, то он вызывает прокрутку. Проверила в Хроме и Лисе - работает одинаково.
Мне отвечали на этом сайте, что это обуславливает свойство overflow родительского элемента (body), которое указывает, что случится, если содержимое выйдет за пределы этого контейнера.

> Свойство 'overflow' действует только на блочные элементы с установленной высотой. В Вашем случае: div - блочный с установленной высотой, img - строчный элемент.

Я установила img display:block, задала ему размеры, но он всё равно ведёт себя так же. Может здесь дело не в overflow? Как сделать, чтобы появлялась прокрутка и при перетаскивании картинки?

Comment: У меня появляется прокрутка при таскании картинки: https://goo.gl/Zf2mtc Что я делаю не так?)

Comment: в каких браузерах тестировалось?

Comment: Если картинку чуть-чуть завести за экран, то появляется маленькая полоса прокрутки, но если её дальше уводить за экран, то прокрутка не увеличивается, в отличие от div. Проверяла в Хроме и Лисе